# Proper usage of 'confine'

Tags: word-usage

Does this sentence correctly use the word 'confine'?

> Would you like to confine our relationship only till Facebook or will you take it further to the next level?

Answer (score 2):

***[Confine (to)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confine):***

> - To keep within bounds; restrict: *Please confine your remarks to the issues at hand. See Synonyms at limit.*

- ...to ***confine*** our relationship only ***to*** Facebook....

(AHD)

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, that use of "confine" seems okay. That said, the sentence as a whole reads quite awkwardly. I don't like the way it starts with "Would you.." and continues with "will..."

I think it would be better to use a more parallel structure:

> Would you like to confine our relationship only to Facebook, or would you like to take it further to the next level?

Also, I probably wouldn't use *confine* in a question like this; it seems like too formal a word for this kind of question. I'd probably word it more like this:

> Would you rather just stay friends on Facebook, or would you be open to taking the next step?